# Defining an Avro Schema

Tags: avro

I have some avro data like this which is printed in terminal.

```
{"cust_status_id":0, "cust_status_description":{"string":" Approved"}}
```

The avro schema which I have created is like

```
{
  "namespace": "com.thp.report.model",
  "type": "record",
  "name": "PraStatusMaster",
  "fields": [
    {
      "name": "cust_status_id",
      "type": "int"
    },
    {
      "name": "cust_status_description",
      "type": "string",
      "avro.java.string": "String"
    }
  ]
}
```

Is the schema correct??

Comment: Removed spring and Kafka tags because they are unrelated to your issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Correct schema for your json is the following one:

```
{
  "name": "PraStatusMaster",
  "type": "record",
  "namespace": "com.thp.report.model",
  "fields": [
    {
      "name": "cust_status_id",
      "type": "int"
    },
    {
      "name": "cust_status_description",
      "type": {
        "name": "cust_status_description",
        "type": "record",
        "fields": [
          {
            "name": "string",
            "type": "string"
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: The fields got properly structure after using this schema. Thanks! But I am getting 0 for the int types and blank value for string.. Can you tell me what could be the problem? @gcallea

Comment: @Vikash Getting those where?

Comment: cust_status_description is not a record. It's a nullable string

Comment: @cricket_007 when I'm printing those in console.